# operator[] ambiguity resolution

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, ambiguity, containment

noob here. The following is a fragment from a class definition I came accross in a book example:

```
double& operator[](int i);
double operator[](int i) const;
```

My question is: **why is this not ambiguous?** When compiling the files of the project, the compiler doesn't give any error.
Also, in the following (imagine AnyClass contains a `valarray<double>` object for example and I want to access it directly):

```
AnyClass test;
cout << test[2]
```

which version does the compiler use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not ambiguous because the `const` is part of the signature and can be used for overload resolution. So if you use `operator[]` on a non-const object, it picks the overload without `const` because that's the most specific one. And if you use it on a const object, it picks the overload with `const` because that's the only one that applies.

Comment: Thanks for that. Totally forgot the implicit argument. And now it makes sense to make a version of operator[] for constants.

Answer (score 1):

If called on a `const` object, the `const` version will be used, else the other one.

That's how the compiler resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: Ohhhh, now I understand. Thanks for your answer. The second would make a version for const in case I want to see a certain element for example. I couldn't understand why... So, cout would use the first version no? Because test is not a constant (and I could also assign it a value as it returns a double&).

Answer (score 1):

```
AnyClass test;
const AnyClass const_test;
std::cout << test[2];       // calls operator[](int)
std::cout << const_test[2]; // calls operator[](int) const
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, you mostly simply need to realize that a `const` on an argument is enough to disambiguate a call:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(char* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "mutable: " << ptr << std::endl;
}

void foo(const char* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "const: " << ptr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* constHello = "hello";
    char mutableHello[] = "hello";
    foo(constHello);
    foo(mutableHello);
}
```

This prints:

> const: hello
>   mutable:hello

The compiler will choose the least restrictive overload it can. So if you use a `char*` when there's a `char*` overload, it's the one it will pick; but if there isn't any, the compiler will decide that casting it to a `const char*` is a viable conversion (the converse is, obviously, not true).

Now, the very simple thing is that all methods pass a `this` pointer as the first parameter of any function. This parameter is hidden for the sake of simplicity. The `const` at the end of the method qualifies the `this` argument. Since, as we've just seen, a `const` on a pointer is enough to disambiguate overloads, this will effectively work.